# How do I update the master that I am going to submit a pull request into (and why did this happen)?

Tags: git, github

I created a branch called `my_branch` and push it to Github. Now when I go to my repo on Github I see `my_branch` listed under "Your recently pushed branches" and a green button on the right that says "Compare & pull request". I click on that. At the top it says "base:master <- compare:my_branch". I scroll down to the code changes below. I see a change in the README.md. On the left a line is highlighted in red that says "This is old". On the right the corresponding line is highlighted in green and says "This is new". My understanding is that the line on the left is master and the right is my_branch. But I didn't make that change; I'm guessing someone else did and updated master. Then (my guess is) I accidentally added it when switching back and forth between `master` and `my_branch`.

But even if I accidentally added it, I'm confused why "This is old" is showing up in master. So I go to the repo on Github and the README.md says "This is new". It says the same thing in `my_branch`. I can't find anywhere that says "This is old" anymore.

I would like to create a pull request that takes the changes I made in `my_branch` and adds them to master. But if I create this pull request it will include a bunch of stuff that I didn't write, and it will appear to be adding things to an old version of master. What did I do and how do I create the correct pull request?

Comment: Can you share the repository?

Comment: just curious, have you try pulling origin/master into your `my_branch` : `git checkout my_branch ; git pull origin master ; git push origin my_branch` then pushing `my_branch` to github and try comparing/creating the PR?

Comment: @Camilo it's a private repo so I can't

Comment: @CarlosParra I haven't so I can try that

Comment: Ok, try. Use the commands I wrote after the ":" above.

Comment: @CarlosParra that might have fixed it...I'm verifying right now

Comment: how did it goes? Let me know if it works, so I can put that as answer, that others with same doubt can see it and try.

Comment: @CarlosParra looks good. Go ahead and submit it as an error and I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pulling `origin/master` into your `my_branch` using the following commands:

```
git checkout my_branch
git pull origin master
```

The first one is to make sure you're in the right branch, then the second command will fetch and merge the latest from `origin/master` in your branch.

Finally, push your branch `my_branch` to GitHub:

```
git push origin my_branch
```

Now, if you go back to GitHub and try to create the PR again, everything from your branch should be up-to-date with your master in origin.